# g++ and omp simd virtual functions

Tags: g++, openmp, simd

I am having little success forcing g++ to generate vector (aka `omp simd`) calls to virtual functions. Consider the base class

```
class vecclass_v {
 public:

#pragma omp declare simd simdlen(4)
  virtual double vecf(double v1, double v2) = 0;
}
```

and a derived class that implements the (should be) vectorized `vecf`

```
class vecclass : public vecclass_v {
 public:

#pragma omp declare simd simdlen(4)
  double vecf(double v1, double v2);
};
```

The implementation is in a `cxx` file. Looking at the object files I can see that g++ correctly generates instances of vectorized functions for the derived class. But calling the virtual function is not resolved to a vectorized call. It uses the scalar member instance instead, e.g., in a usecase like this one

```
vecclass_v *ob = [get an instance of vecclass somewhere]
ob->vecf(a, b); // this should be vectorized, but is not
```

The Intel compiler does support vectorized virtual functions (https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/virtual-vector-function-supported-in-intel-c-compiler-170). Does g++ support this, but I just can't use it, or is this not implemented yet?